# Проблема с import из файла

Tags: python

Добрый день возникла проблема с импортом переменной из другого файла, пытался написать рассылку телеграмму где жаловался на оскорбления от другого пользователя, в файле message.py было готовое сообщение, а в test.py я проверял как это работает, чтобы дай бог не накосячить с main.py.
Содержимое message.py:

```
 message = '''
 [user]систематически оскорбляет меня, используя унизительные выражения и провоцируя конфликты. Эти действия создают негативную атмосферу общения и мешают мне чувствовать себя комфортно в Telegram.

Прошу принять необходимые меры в отношении данного пользователя.

Спасибо за понимание и оперативное реагирование.'''
```

содержимое test.py:

```
from message.py import message
user = input("Введите юзер:")
result = user + message
print(result)
```

Сама ошибка:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'message.py'; 'message' is not a package

За ранее спасибо.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: При импорте расширение файла писать не надо, точка в импорте используется для другого

Comment: `from message import message`

Answer (score 0):

если ты знаешь импортировать из другого файла какую-нибудь функцию,
то это надо сделать так:

```py
from file import function
```

Просто убери .py

Comment: функцию или переменную*

Comment: Зачем отвечать самому себе. Просто можно отредактировать пост

Comment: @vitidev, писал с мобильного приложения, где почти ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0):

```
import message

user = input("Введите юзер:")
result = user + message.message
print(result)
```

попробуй так